# validate empty textboxes before leaving the textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp-classic, textbox

I am developing an asp web application and I have an online form, I can already prompt the users that the text box is empty after clicking the submit button, however I want to prompt the user that the textbox cannot be left blank..

for example last name, middle name, and first name, when I am on the last name field, and I went to the middle name field, the last name textbox was left empty, I want to prompt the users that the last name textbox was left empty, and when there is already value, the prompt will be removed,

also i want the textbox to be bordered red then resume to normal when there is value,, thanks for your answers

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript. Look at the onBlur event (lost focus) then set the style accordingly.

Comment: whatever you want is good but can you show us what you have tried what problem you faced using your code.

Comment: right now I am still using if (TextBox1.Text =="") //prompt that text box is empty, and so on

Comment: now i want it before the user leaves the textbox

Comment: @JbMeris See what i wanted to tell is you add these code in your question, If you post these in comments some may see some may not and to get an answer quickly provide all the info you can in question like what you tried and what problem you are facing or what error message you are getting.

Comment: You should also clarify - are you using asp.net or classic asp? The former has some validation libraries that make this easier. Edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to validate empty textboxes and change the border color to red when textbox is left empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356970/i-want-to-validate-empty-textboxes-and-change-the-border-color-to-red-when-textb)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, then use data annotations or you can use any jquery validation library like http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html