# I want to validate empty textboxes and change the border color to red when textbox is left empty

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp-classic, textbox

Here is my code so far, when I click on the first textbox and leave it blank, the border color changes to red, and prompts me that it is empty, but when i go to my other field, and leave it empty, it still prompts me that my first textbox is empty and not the second  textbox, and if i put a value on the first text box, that's when the border color changes to green, and its also the time that im prompted that my second input is empty, i want it to be done consecutively like the one in yahoo mail registration, help please

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             function CheckBlank(txt) {
                 var policyno = document.getElementById('txtPolNo');
                 var issuanceoffice = document.getElementById('dropIssOff');
                 if (policyno.value == '')
                 {
                     document.getElementById('txtPolNo').style.border= "solid 3px red";
                     alert('Policy Number is Required');

                     return false;
                 }  
                 else if (issuanceoffice.value == 'Select') {
                     document.getElementById('dropIssOff').style.border = "solid 3px red";
                     alert('Please Select Issuance Office');

                     return false;
                 }
                 else {
                     document.getElementById('txtPolNo').style.border = "solid 3px green";
                     document.getElementById('dropIssOff').style.border = "solid 3px green";
                     return true;
                 }






             }
    </script>
```

Comment: I suggest you look at jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like there's two things you might want to be aware of: 1) Instead of starting a new question, edit the body of the [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355516/validate-empty-textboxes-before-leaving-the-textbox) when you have new information on that one question. 2) You should also clarify - are you using asp.net or classic asp? They are two different technologies and the former has some validation libraries that make this easier. Edit your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function CheckBlank(txt) {
             var policyno = document.getElementById('txtPolNo').value.trim();
             var issuanceoffice = document.getElementById('dropIssOff').selecteditem;
             if (policyno.value == '')
             {
                 document.getElementById('txtPolNo').style.border= "solid 3px red";
                 alert('Policy Number is Required');
                 document.getElementById('txtPolNo').focus();

                 return false;
             }  
             if (issuanceoffice.value == 'Select') {
                 document.getElementById('dropIssOff').style.border = "solid 3px red";
                 alert('Please Select Issuance Office');
                 document.getElementById('txtPolNo').focus();
                 return false;
             }
             if(policyno.value != '' && issuanceoffice.value != 'Select')
             {
                 document.getElementById('txtPolNo').style.border = "solid 3px green";
                 document.getElementById('dropIssOff').style.border = "solid 3px green";
                 return true;
             }






         }
</script>
```

try this...